# Inline block leaves a border in ng-recaptcha

Tags: css, angular

```
<div class="text-center">
          <re-captcha
           [ngClass]="{'face err-captcha': captchaResponse==false && submitted}"
          class="recaptcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey={{captchaSiteKey}}>
          </re-captcha>
     </div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frn1s.jpg)

If I dont use inline block then that captcha block doesn't get centered. When I remove it then border goes away but the captcha gets out of order.

```
 .recaptcha {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

With black background, [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckv5l.jpg) it actually not a border but looks like one. If there is a way to center it without using inline block that might do the trick.

```
.recaptcha {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #080808;
}
```

Comment: can you share the HTML

Comment: I think that border came from the captcha element, Can you set the border and box shadow none for the captcha element

Comment: Doesnt work `background: transparent; ` works but when i give my own border to the captcha the empty space between the element and the border gets visible

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for display: inline-block; So there are some solutions to this:
1. margin-right(or any side where this space or border coming): -1px;
2. font-size: 0; to the parent and give deired font size in inner items

3. `<div class="text-center"><re-captcha [ngClass]="{'face err-captcha': captchaResponse==false && submitted}" class="recaptcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey={{captchaSiteKey}}></re-captcha</div>`

3rd one is may be looks wired to you but this is also a cool solution. remove all the space and enters from your code, basically minimize it.